# System.StackOverflowException in IronPython program

Tags: asp.net, ironpython

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional SP1, and I have an asp.net with IronPython 2.6.911.0 website

I added a funciones.dll file to the bin folder of the simplest aspx.py file possible (just created). I added "import funciones" to the codefile and I got this. "unhanddled exception of type  'System.StackOverflowException' in mscorlib.dll" and the disassembler stops in "System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject" 00000040  mov         edx,eax

I simplified the code of "funciones.dll" to this to see if there was a problem with it, and Im still getting it.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
from System.Data import *
clr.AddReference('System')
import System
clr.AddReference('System.Web')
import System.Web

def escribircontroles(objeto):
    pass
```

Comment: which line is throwing the error?

Comment: All I get as description of the error is the above mentioned message and an arrow pointing to a disassembled code in the line
00000040  mov         edx,eax . The file which calls that dll file with that code posted above just has a code

def Page_Load(sender, e):
    import funciones

Comment: in fact, since it's a test code only to see why importing funciones fails it also can have import funciones and it fails the same way

Comment: this is likely an issue of integration of IronPython with asp.net, since in another website Im not getting it, but Im not sure what's the difference. One is the other website has IronPython 2.0 dlls in the bin folder but it could be another issue. In the other project Im able to import the dlls but Im not able to use the functions or methods in it, they cant be found when you call them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently the problem was related to the version of IronPython with which was compiled funciones.py along with a different version of the IronPython dlls in the bin folder